# Can someone help me figure out what this TiKZ code does?

Tags: tikz-pgf

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

\begin{document}
    \newcommand{\xmax}{14}
    \newcommand{\fmin}{(pi/3)}
    \newcommand{\fmax}{(2*pi)}
\begin{tikzpicture}[domain=0:\xmax, samples=500]

\draw[ultra thick, red] plot (\x, {sin(deg(exp(ln(\fmin)+\x/\xmax*(ln(\fmax)-ln(\fmin)))*\x))} );

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I would understand if LaTeX repeat the code below this statement many times.

Comment: this is begin of picture in which is drawn some function on defined domain. function is determined in 500 points.

Comment: ok, I've adde all the code. So you can see the function.
what does the domain mean?
And what does "determined in 500 points" mean?

Comment: The domain is the range of the x values to be used for your plot. The `samples=500` argument instructs the plot to be done with 500 points in the given domain (this may be used for smoothing the output).

Comment: so, it is a kind of cycle (\foreach...), but, where is x the variable that assume this value?

Comment: variable is `\x` ..., please read documentation for `tikz`,: TikZ & PGF manual v3.0.1a, page 326: *22 Plots of Functions*

Comment: Ok, so the variable \x will assume the value from 0 to (the value of) \xmax and the \draw function will be repeated  the number of time the value of \x is on this intervall. But with samples=500, \x will never be evaluated. Is it so?

Comment: Not exactly; `\x`  will assume the values for 0 to `\xmax`; the function in the `plot` will be evaluated for every value of `\x`, obtaining a list of coordinates `(\x, ` *f(* `\x` *)* `)`, which are then united by a stroke (or whatever you define in the option of the `draw` command).

Comment: @Rmano: thank you. Now I've understand. Can you suggest me how to invert this function. I mean: onde con alta frequenza prima e bassa frequenza più tardi

Comment: mhhh... this seems a XY-problem: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: I think we already had this. `exp(ln(\fmin)+\x/\xmax*(ln(\fmax)-ln(\fmin)))=\fmin*(\fmax/\fmin)^(\x/\xmax)`, so this is a function that equals `\fmin` at `\x=0` and `\fmax` at `\x=\xmax` and has a power law interpolation in between. I really believe you should go the other way: make some requirements and try to find a function that satisfies them. If you cannot find such a function, you can still ask for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will simply add comments in the code that will hopefully explain everything

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    % define some constants
    \newcommand{\xmax}{14}
    \newcommand{\fmin}{(pi/3)}
    \newcommand{\fmax}{(2*pi)}

% begin a tikzpicture that will pass the options domain and samples with the given value to each command inside of it.
\begin{tikzpicture}[domain=0:\xmax, samples=500]

% Use the plot command from tikz on the given function.
% the function will be evaluated between 0 < x < 500 as these were the borders specified in the domain-option
% in total 500 equidistant points of this function will be calculated as this was the value for the samples option
% Every calculated point will be connected to its neighbours which will raise the impression
% that the function was indeed plotted continuously and not for discrete values only.
% You will see what I mean when you set samples to a low value like 5 or something like that.
% In total the function will be evaluated 500 times. Every time \x is set to the respective value and it is up to the code to actually draw a point.
% This is done by the normal coordinate specification in which \x is used as the x-coordinate and the result of the function as the y-coordinate.
% This results in a normal (<number>,{<mathematical expression>}) syntax for coordinates
\draw[ultra thick, red] plot (\x, {sin(deg(exp(ln(\fmin)+\x/\xmax*(ln(\fmax)-ln(\fmin)))*\x))} );

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```